# How to add new column from calculation on two rows in power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have following table:

[image]

I want to add a new column "Total" using query editor(power Query) such that when "GL" is 'Gross Margin' then "Total" should be 'Gross Margin' on "Total India Market" multiplied by 'Total Net Sales' on "Total India Market" i.e 0.11*65687 and if "GL" is not 'Gross Margin' then "Total India Market"+"Export".

Desired output should look like below:

[image]

I do not want calculated column it should be in a query editor i.e power query.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that `Total Net Sales` is always on the row before `Gross Margin`.

If that is the case, then in order to multiply a value by the value in the same column preceding row, you'll need to either add an Index column, or, my preference because it calculates faster, add a "shifted column" where the value from the previous row is now on the same row.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("bZA/C4MwEMW/ijhLzWlyf0anTu2idBEHBykFacHY799LAqXELnnc8Xv3HhnHEkwNNVBZlZ33y14M7+2pw8kIR0FKE5VT9UsPr31ei6s6+nldvG6IBVXQIQegbZx1mem8vbwvLvN2f8QQaDCKiSEAeUh/68JhxxQ4JomX9eUv2fwrDwYCL2hMiuEMP7YPcMhCS6JqWxaTmQ7tQZLY+EWMGZ/a62EJHECb6oNzjrTQ9AE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Date = _t, GL = _t, #"Domestic Product" = _t, #"Total India Market" = _t, Export = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"GL", type text}, 
        {"Domestic Product", type number}, {"Total India Market", type number}, {"Export", type number}}),

//add a column = offset column from Total India Market
//This will calculate faster than using an INDEX column
    offsetTotalIndiaMarket = 
        let 
            tbl = #"Changed Type",
            ShiftedList = {null} & List.RemoveLastN(tbl[Total India Market]),
            Custom1 = Table.ToColumns(tbl) & {ShiftedList}
        in
            Table.FromColumns(Custom1, Table.ColumnNames(tbl) & {"Shifted Tot India Market"}),

//add custom column to execute the described calculation
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(offsetTotalIndiaMarket, "Total", each 
        if [GL] = "Gross Margin" 
        then [Total India Market]*[Shifted Tot India Market] 
        else [Total India Market]+[Export]),

//Remove shifted column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Shifted Tot India Market"})

in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

**Results**

[image]

*If it is **NOT** the case that `Total Net Sales` is always on the line preceding `Gross Margin`, then we can use a different algorithm.  But also have to know if `Gross Margin` will **always** have a preceding `Total Net Sales`, or if we have to account for an inability to calculate also.*

*If this is the case, respond with a comment to this answer*

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using power query

First add an index column then calculate previous row for Total India Market and then add custom column to calculate total as per requirement

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\anumua2\Downloads\im_25_oct_21.xlsx"), null, true),
    Data_Sheet = Source{[Item="Data",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Data_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Date", type date}, {"GL", type text}, {"Domestic Product", type number}, {"Total India Market", type number}, {"Export", type number}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Prev" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each #"Added Index"{[Index]-2}[#"Total India Market"]),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(Prev,{{"Custom", "Prev_Total India Market"}}),
    #"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Renamed Columns", {{"Prev_Total India Market", 0}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Errors", "Custom", each if[GL] = "Gross Margin" then [Total India Market]*[Prev_Total India Market] else [Total India Market] + [Export]),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Custom",{{"Custom", "Total"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns1"
```

[image]